# Developing in the cloud

Tags: workflow, cloud

I wondering if anyone has tried a pure cloud based development setup, and if so how?

Background:

I'm going traveling for about six weeks in Costa Rica, my wife has already forbidden the laptop.  I'm worried about being able to provide support to some of the projects I currently have going.  While I won't have access to my laptop, I will have access to internet cafes, but the likely hood of being allowed to download source code, let alone install any of my normal development tools is doubtful.  I will however have access to a web browser.

My initial thoughts through googling is getting a slice on [slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com).  This way I would have a 'machine' complete with ajax console access.

Then using something like [Bespin](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/bespin/) to act as a web based editor.

Combined with some Capistrano recipies and my github account.  I think it just might work for my RAILS and PHP projects.

Anyone else tried something like this?

Any thoughst / opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too bad if wife forbids the laptop. have a nice trip.

Comment: Buy a new desktop computer once in Costa Rica.

Comment: Down tools, relax and enjoy your holiday :)

Comment: my solution....
wife: "NO LAPTOP for you!"
me: "NO COSTA RICA for you!"
:)

Comment: Even though this is primarily for the trip, I could see this type of workflow being useful in other ways.  While I'm not often without my laptop, I'm always within mins of a web browser if the need to code hits me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Bespin project from Mozilla. You'll need to setup your Bespin Backend. The installation is quite long but I'm *preparing* an article on www.beroux.com if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

For $5 a month, you can get an account with [GoToSSH](http://www.gotossh.com/), which is a web-based SSH client. If your web servers support SSH, you can use it to log in remotely and edit your files using vi/emacs/pico/whatever. Of course, this presumes you don't mind bypassing your source control for the sake of being able to quickly deploy fixes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few java applet ssh clients you could set up an a machine.  I've used mindterm, but it's abandoned.

If the Internet cafe has Windows machines where you can install software, then you're all set. (not uncommon; I was usually able to install putty so I could check my email in Austria, Germany, and Italy on a 3-week trip in 2005.)  WinSCP lets you run a text editor on remote files, which would otherwise be painful over a high-latency connection.  Most version control systems have command line interfaces, so that should cover most of it.

I'm an old-school command line junkie, so I'm fine with ssh...  Your needs may vary.

Just make sure your remote machine has a good UPS and will boot up ok after a power cycle.  You'll be too far away to nudge it along if you haven't tested rebooting since last time you changed any config files.

Answer (score 1):

Check [MacinCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/). It allow user to access a Mac through your mobile devices. Plus, it contains diversity of developing programs, which may help your RAILS and PHP projects. The best plan for you might be a 3-Hour Daily Limit Manage Servers plan, which charge 20$/month.

But I'm sure the best way is to fight for your laptop.